# JS How to make button connect with script

Tags: javascript, button

How to make connect button with my javascript ?

My JS compares 2 times and display greater, but i see result when edit object, i need help with, how connect my script with button.

When i click button then achieve my scripy and display alert with message.

Comment: He people, stop downvoting it, its the first question!

Comment: Can you explain more your problem by showing your snippet?

Comment: @CoolGadgetsForGeeks, Not sure why you think first question should be upvoted even if has **multiple** problems. I agree commenting what are the problems and how he can improve it could be nice.

Comment: @gdoron I didn't mean upvoting would be good. But everybody bashing the question down without any comments is not really helpful for new and inexperienced users...

Comment: @CoolGadgetsForGeeks, once it's closed, and now it's, you can see the reasons for it and learn how to improve your questions.

Comment: @gdoron OK, cool, didn't know that. Didn't see the "off-topic" close before :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make a button in html and assing a JavaScript function on button's click event:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
        function myFunction(){
            // do something
        }
    </script>

    <button onclick="myFunction();">Execute</button>
```

Comment: button is in SharePoint end is made, i will connect with made button

Answer (score 1):

If it is a asp.net button:

```
<asp:Button ID="searchButton" runat="server" Text="Go" OnClientClick="return Search();" OnClick="search_Click" />
```

Then define `Search` in javascript.

If it is html button:

```
<input type="button" id="searchButton" value="Go" onclick="javascript:Search()"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
function Search(){
    ...
    ...
    ...
}
</script>
```